# Links to folders that don't work

Tags: directory, 23.10

I have a problem in my personal folder, there are links with error that i cann't resolve. I take a problem in the last days, that my desktop shows the icons of my personal folder, but I resolved this with other questions.

Show my personal folder to view the icons with red cross...
[image]

What can i do??

There are links that must be folders....

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I assume that "Carpeta Personal" is the same as $HOME.

To display where the links point, do this:

- Open a Terminal, hold CTRL+ALT and hit T
- type a single `cd` and hit ENTER - this ensures you're in $HOME
- type `ls -l` *(append `| grep ^l` to display only links)* and hit ENTER

This will list the files in your home folder and also tell where the links are pointing to.
For SOFT links to display and work correctly the destinations must be on a **mounted** volume/disk/partition.
HARD links can only point to the same partition, soft links can point anywhere but display without errors and work only when the destination exists and/or is mounted.

ref: `man ln` + ENTER

Comment: Yes, "Carpeta Personal" is my home. The links that show ls -l are recurrents, arrive to the same folder. May be this changes from directory to links? How can I change from links to directory? I will go to put and image in the question.

Comment: And as you discovered, linking back to the original is hardly useful, and apparently **detected** as a "bad thing".

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it with the file /home/USUARIO/.config/user-dirs.dirs, like say in this article... https://cambiatealinux.com/cambiar-la-ruta-de-las-carpetas-del-perfil-de-usuario-en-ubuntu-y-derivados

I remove the broken links, make a new folder and change the path at the file. When i reboot the system, take the new path.

Thank you!!!